# Simple 2 equations and 2 unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am reading the second partial derivative test example, but I am suck on the following step:

$$f(x,y) = -x^3 + 4xy - 2y^2 + 1$$

And we have the partial derivatives as follow...

$$f_x(x,y) = -3x^2 + 4y$$

$$f_y(x,y) = 4x - 4y$$

The critical points are $(0, 0)$ and $(\frac{4}{3}, \frac{4}{3})$. My question is how does $(\frac{4}{3}, \frac{4}{3})$ comes from as a solution? I am thinking it has to do with, substituting $x=y$ into $f_x(x,y)$ and... completing the square?

Comment: Yes, you should think about it. $3x^2=4x$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A critical point has $f_x = f_y = 0$. So you want to solve:

$$0 = f_x(x, x) = -3x^2 + 4x = x (4-3x)$$

No need to complete the square.

Answer (score 4):

We want the partial derivatives to be zero, so the expressions become

$$0 = -3x^2 + 4y$$
$$0 = 4x - 4y$$

Both expressions have the $4y$ term in common, giving us $4y = 3x^2$ and $4y = 4x$. Together, this means

$$4x = 3x^2$$

Giving us $x=0$ and $x=4/3$. Substituing $x=4/3$ into one of the original expressions gives us corresponding value of $y$.